Sort by another column - working in one visual but not another
I am trying to sort the line chart on the right the same way as the table on the left.

Both are using a variable (Week) that is sorted by another column (a custom ranking column I created in a separate table, and linked to my main data). The table works perfectly - I want it to start at Week 40 and proceed from there. But the line chart X axis is starting at 0, despite using the same variable. I cannot understand why it isn't working in the same way.
The weird lines that run across the middle of the chart suggest that the line is actually tracking correctly - starting at 40 and running through to 52 then going to 1 and continuing on to 39. But for some reason the axis is still ordered 0-52. I have no idea why.

Maybe use a category axis, instead of a time/ordered axis?

That was it! Thank you so much!!
